# If there is an infinite number of universes doesn't that mean there is a universe where there is not an infinite number of parallel universes?

Tags: multiverse

Hi i'm not clever enough to think outside of my finite existence. Can someone explain the bounds of my logical thinking that infinity is a paradox like the question: "are you lying?". Is my understanding of multiverse even correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are thinking about the many worlds interpretation of quantum physics, this paradox can’t arise.

The many worlds interpretation is that whenever a quantum state is in a superposition and is measured, the universe splits into 2 or more new universes, with each one having the superposition collapse into a different state.

So, for example, if you had an electron in the spin state of
$|\psi>=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|\frac{1}{2}>+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|-\frac{1}{2}>$ and you measured its spin, the universe would split into 2, one where you measure spin $\frac{1}{2}$ and one where you measure spin $-\frac{1}{2}$.

So to get back to your paradox, if the many worlds interpretation is correct in the hypothetical original universe (before any measurements have been taken),it must also be true in all daughter universes, as it would be a fundamental law of physics, not something that can differ each time it is measured.

Comment: The OP is talking about the multiverse theory, not the many worlds interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

An infinite number of worlds does not mean "everything that can be stated."  They still must be able to satisfy the model we are talking to.  The way you use the phrase "if there are an infinite number of universes," implies you are only looking at the case where there is a multiverse of infinite number of universes.  In such a system, a universe that is a part of that multiverse but does not have an infinite number of "sister universes" is not satisfiable.  It's something that can't be done because of the language used to phrase it, without even bringing into question the physical implications of a multiverse.

That being said, the easiest example of this would be the even numbers.  There are an infinite number of even numbers, but there does not exist a single even number that is odd.  Just because there's an infinite number of them does not mean that there is certainly a number which satisfies any arbitrary property, such as being odd.

Answer (score 0):

By definition all universes are "parallel" to each other and "the nothingness" separates them. So the answer is no, there is no such universe if you assume that there are an infinite number of them. You cannot have a pentagon of 4 sides.